# Docker unable to setup rails up with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I am new to docker . I try to setup my rails app with docker . I use postgresql for database . I use fig for this. when i run

```
fig run web rake db:create
```

i got error `"could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"."`

any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: does PostgreSQL service is running ??

Comment: yes, i use image orchardup/postgres .

Comment: ok show your entries in pg_hba.conf ??